# Alternate version of the Euler-Maclaurin summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example given an alternate series, I can use the exponential translation operator $ e^{aD}f(0)=f(a)$ to get

$$ f(0)-f(1)+f(2)-\ldots= \frac{1}{1+E^{D}}f(0) $$

If I use the expansion $$ \frac{1}{1+\exp(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}k_{n}x^{n} $$

then our original sum becomes

$$ f(0)-f(1)+f(2)-\ldots= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}k_{n}D^{n}f(0)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Euler-Boole's summation handled in this paper (Borwein & al, 2009, revisited): https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/eulerboole.pdf

Comment: I'm not used with this type of $e^{aD}$-notation. But I remember to have found the matrix-solution to the that alternating, and then nonalternating, sum of function at consecutive arguments. See here: http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/04_3_SummingOfLikePowers.pdf (...)

Comment: (...)Originally I found this for the sum-of-like-powers, but it can be applied to other functions as well. The key-formula for finding the matrix $ETA$ is $ETA=(I+P)^{-1}$ (which might be written as ${ I \over I + P}$) where $P$ is the Pascal-matrix. Moreover the Pascalmatrix can be seen as exponential of some other matrix containing the coefficients for the derivative of a power series.